# Symbolizing multiple occurrences at the same address

Tags: qgis, point

I would like to have the size of the point on my map change to represent multiple occurrences on an event at the same address.  I imported the data from a CSV file.

I'm using QGIS 2.16

Comment: What software package are you using? The methods and capabilities differ greatly between packages.

Comment: Will the size of the point vary in accordance with the number of occurrences? E.g. point size increases as number of occurrences increases? Or, did you just want two sizes: one point size for where there is a single occurrence, and another point size for where there are multiple occurrences?

Answer (score 2):

Open `Layer Properties` panel and click on the `Data defined override` icon of *Size* parameter. It will open *Expression String Builder* window.

Give an expression: `count('ID', group_by:= geom_to_wkt($geometry))` 
(... I added `*2` just to exaggerate the size).

[image]

Output is:

[image]